# Solution to $A = BX + YC$ where $A$ is a square matrix of rank $n$, $B,C$ known, rank $m<n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I hope this isn't too trivial of a problem. I'm really struggling with it and I feel like it shouldn't be that difficult.

As stated in the title:

Given (full rank):
$A\in\mathbb{R}_{nxn}$
$B\in\mathbb{R}_{nxm}$
$C\in\mathbb{R}_{mxn}$
with $n> m\ge n/2$

Find:
$X\in\mathbb{R}_{mxn}$
$Y\in\mathbb{R}_{nxm}$

That satisfies

$A =  BX + YC$

If we knew Y instead of C this *would* be a trivial problem.
What I understand:
Since $BX$ and $YC$ can have at most rank $m$ each, then at the very minimum, $m\ge n/2$.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $n=2m$. Then it is not difficult to solve the equation. We rewrite it as follows:
$\begin{pmatrix}A_1&A_2\\A_3&A_4\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}B_1\\B_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}X_1&X_2\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}Y_1\\Y_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}C_1&C_2\end{pmatrix}$, that is $A_1=B_1X_1+Y_1C_1,A_2=B_1X_2+Y_1C_2,A_3=B_2X_1+Y_2C_1,A_4=B_2X_2+Y_2C_2$. We assume that $B_1,B_2,C_1,C_2$ are invertible matrices.

EDIT. Thus $X_1=B_1^{-1}(A_1-Y_1C_1)=B_2^{-1}(A_3-Y_2C_1)$, that implies a relation of the form $Y_1=PY_2+Q$ (cf. the Dar's calculation below). In the same way, from the 2 other equations, we obtain a relation of the form: $Y_1=PY_2+R$, that implies $Q=R$ (otherwise, there are no solutions). This necessary condition is a relation linking $A,B,C$. The sequel is easy.

Comment: OH this is a really good one!  My research just started recently needing linear algebra and so these sort of tricks are all new to me.  Really helpful!

Comment: The invertability of $B_1$,$B_2$,$C_1$ hinges on them being of rank m correct?

Comment: OK, so if we solve for $Y_1$ using the $X_1$ equalities, we find:  
$$Y_1 = A_{1}C_{1}^{-1} - B_{1}B_{2}^{-1}A_{3}C_{1}^{-1}+B_{1}B_{2}^{-1}Y_{2}$$  
Similarly solving for $X_2$ being equal, we get a second equality:  
$$  Y_1 = A_{2}C_{2}^{-1} - B_{1}B_{2}^{-1}A_{4}C_{2}^{-1}+B_{1}B_{2}^{-1}Y_{2}$$

We see that

$$ A_{1}C_{1}^{-1} - B_{1}B_{2}^{-1}A_{3}C_{1}^{-1} = A_{2}C_{2}^{-1} - B_{1}B_{2}^{-1}A_{4}C_{2}^{-1}$$

Similar constraints pop out of other equalities, so this can't be solved without these constraints being met.

Comment: @loup blanc    Nice idea! However your method relies on $B_2$ and $C_2$ to be invertible, which is not guaranteed by the assumptions.

Comment: I don't think I commuted anything...

$X_1$ Equality:
$$X_1=B^{−1}_1(A_1−Y_1C_1)=B^{−1}_2(A_3−Y_2C_1) \\
A_1-Y_1C_1= B_1B_2^{-1}A_3 - B_1B_2^{-1}Y_2C_1  \\
Y_1C_1=A_1- B_1B_2^{-1}A_3 + B_1B_2^{-1}Y_2C_1  \\
Y_1=A_1C_1^{-1}- B_1B_2^{-1}A_3C_1^{-1} + B_1B_2^{-1}Y_2$$
$X_2$ Equality:
$$X_2=B^{−1}_1(A_2−Y_1C_2)=B^{−1}_2(A_4−Y_2C_2) \\
A_2-Y_1C_2= B_1B_2^{-1}A_4 - B_1B_2^{-1}Y_2C_2  \\
Y_1C_2=A_2- B_1B_2^{-1}A_4 + B_1B_2^{-1}Y_2C_2  \\
Y_1=A_1C_2^{-1}- B_1B_2^{-1}A_4C_2^{-1} + B_1B_2^{-1}Y_2$$

Comment: @ Dar . OK, there are simplifications; I did not do the calculation ! I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Take $n=2$, $m=1$, and
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1},\  B= \pmatrix{0\\1}, \ C=\pmatrix{0 & 1}.
$$
Then you want to find $X=\pmatrix{x_1&x_2},Y=\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2}$ to satisfy
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} = \pmatrix{0\\1}\pmatrix{x_1&x_2} +\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2}\pmatrix{0 & 1} = \pmatrix{0&y_1\\x_1&x_2+y_2},
$$
which is impossible.

The same is true if instead  $C$ is unknown, and $Y$ is given with $Y=B$.

Comment: It's not a guaranteed solution without further limits, I assume it has something to do with the rank([B,C']) must equal n?